# Perl - Match string between two colons

Tags: regex, perl

My string looks like this

```
important stuff: some text 2: some text 3.
```

I want to only print "important stuff". So basically I want to print everything up to the first colon. I'm sure this is simple, but my regex foo is not so good.

Edit: Sorry I was doing something stupid and gave you a bad example line. It has been corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just restrict what you're matching to non-colons, `[^:]*`.  Note, the `^` and `:` boundaries aren't actually needed, but they help document the intent behind the regex.

```
my $text = "important stuff: some text 2: some text 3."

if ($text =~ /^([^:]*):/) {
    print "$1";
}
```

Comment: Sorry I gave you a bad example line. It was working correctly when I used my original example. I actually need it to match everything up to the first colon. thanks for the help so far!

Comment: You beat me to the answer, on my hashed edits so I gave you a vote too.

Comment: @hypnotoad I've editted the response for your revised spec.  The only thing that needed to be changed were the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider just `split`ting on the colon:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'important stuff: some text 2: some text 3.';
my $important = ( split /:/, $string )[0];
print $important;
```

Output:

```
important stuff
```

Comment: +1 for the most efficient answer by a factor of ten.  It's on-par with `$important = substr $string, 0, index($string, ':');`, but more Perlish. ;)

Comment: @DavidO - Appreciate your comments.  Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to mention, do use the third param of split to cause split to stop working after it finds the colon: `(split /:/, $ string, 2)[0]`. (That's what I did when I tested.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, assume its a string

```
$test = "sass sg22gssg 22222 2222:  important  important  :"

Assume you want all characters between.

Wrong answer: $test =~ /:(.+):/;  # thank you for the change from .{1,}

Corrected. 
$test =~ /:([^:]*):/; 

print $1; #perl  memory u can assign to a string ;
```

$found = $1;

As a cheat sheet of regex in perl. [cheat sheet](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html)

I did test it.

Comment: it gets a bit more complex if you want to match multiple : x : matches, the g can to match over and over and get an array  from that.

Comment: `{1,}` is usually just specified as `+`.  and if there are newlines, you will need the /s flag to make `.` match them

Comment: Yes, I am more stressing that the {1,} must match one character, I have found some odd (no evidence,just feeling) that + matches zero  also. I should try that.

Comment: `*` matches 0 or more, `+` matches 1 or more.

Comment: @hypnotoad: it shouldn't, unless there are newlines between the first set of colons.  if there are, do `/:(.+):/s` instead (or do `/:([^:]*):/` as in the other answer)

Comment: By George your right, slap me up side the head. let me look at this a bit more.  :)

Comment: Silly me . matches any character and fails, * matches correctly. Do think I will edit when I have more coffee.

Comment: Sorry guys I gave you a bad example line. It was working correctly when I used my original example. I actually need it to match everything up to the first colon. thanks for the help so far!

Comment: no need to be sorry, I made a hash of my edits :) '$test =~ /^([^:]*):/;'

Comment: @alexmac Your first regex would've worked if you had done non-greedy matching, `:(.*?):`  I personally like restricting the allowed character set for a matched value instead of just relying on boundary conditions, as that is often faster and also less prone to simple mistakes like forgetting to do non-greedy versus greedy.